# How to flag comments as spam?

Tags: support, comments, flags, spam, comment-flags

When I try to flag a comment, I am offered the following possibilities.

- rude or offensive
- not constructive
- obsolete
- too chatty
- other..

[image: Screenshot - flag comment]

Which of them should I choose in situation when a comment contains something which would qualify as spam, i.e., post containing the same content would be [flagged as spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor)?

Admittedly, typically the spammers do not have [enough reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) to post comments in other places than under their posts. (Which is the situation I saw a while ago and it prompted me to ask this.) In the specific situation, that I have already flagged the post, there is no need to do about the comment right?

I assume that the situation that a spammer would have enough rep to post comments anywhere is probably very rare (if it happenst at all). Still I would like to know also what to do in such situation.

**TL;DR:** If a spam comment is posted under an answer I already flagged, should I flag also the comment? What should I do in (probably very rare) situation when a spam comment is posted under a post (answer/question) which does not contain spam?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Comment on blatant spam answer** – If you are certain that every reasonable user or moderator agrees that the post shall be deleted, flag it and do not bother about flagging the comments. Either the post will be deleted by six spam flags from regular users or a moderator will see handle the flag first. In both cases, the comment will be deleted and there is no additional need to raise a moderator’s attention.
2. **Comment on subtle or borderline spam post** – If you have doubts about the post being deleted (e.g., because an answer actually addresses the question but lacks disclosure), raise a flag on the comment as well. If no five other users agree with your spam flag, it will eventually trickle up to the moderators, so there is no need to worry about wasting moderator time. Moreover, moderators are busy people (at least on some sites), and it would not be good if the handling moderator missed the comment.
3. **Comment on regular post** – Flag the comment for moderator attention. If a user abuses the comment privilege to spam, the moderators will want to know about this. If you flag the comment as anything else, it may happen that it is deleted by user flags alone (yes, this is possible; though it rarely happens).

Answer (score 8):

You allude to it already yourself: since commenting on any question or answer that is not your own requires 50 reputation, it's unlikely that a spammer will

1. Acquire sufficient reputation to be able to comment spam
2. Spam comment their own question or answer in preference to that question or answer being itself spam.

So given that spam comments happen so infrequently, the already-available "other" option is probably sufficient.

Comment: This is not true.  There are sites that allow comments with only 1 rep. [Stack Apps, for example](https://stackapps.com/help/privileges/).